# How to pull keys and values in jq csv when you don't know the key name

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have a semi working jq filter that pulls out `.key, .value.sitename` and shows it in a one line csv format. I'd like to add any `tag_*` keys and values (if found) at the end of the csv line.

```
[.key , .value.hostname, .value.attributes.sitename  ] | @csv
```

I need help with the `.value.attributes.tag*` keys since they might be completely missing or different `tag_` names. They all start with `tag_` but could be anything. I'd like to pair the found tag name and value together if possible and append it on the csv line with the host.

```
{
  "key": "computer1.domain.com",
  "value": {
    "attributes": {
      "TESTID": "23423423",
      "sitename": "siteidname",
      "tag_robo_equip": "boopbeep",
      "tag_modern": "cybertruck"
    },
    "hostname": "computer1.domain.com",
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind including the expected output for that sample in your question?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the line "hostname": "computer1.domain.com", the comma is an error.
If you correct this, the solution could be:
[Proposal](https://jqplay.org/s/bOkLsBlfNn)

At the you have 2 additional columns one with the keys an other with the values in your csv file.